# R cannot be resolved to a variable, XML issue?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, adt

I opened my old project, which worked correctly few moths ago.
Now I've eclipse bug or something connected with the error in almost every activity - `R cannot be resolved to a variable`.

[image]

I did all actions readed on stackoverflow, but nothing worked yet:

- imports checked
- project cleaned

[image]

I think problem may be in one of the XML files , which also contain 3 errors like `No resource identifier found for attribute "atribute" in package my.package`

In this activity I'm using a facebook samples to share content.
Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    Copyright 2010-present Facebook.

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#FFF"
        >
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:background="#FFF"
                  android:id="@+id/activity_share_ui_container">
        <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton   <!-- 2 errors here --->
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                facebook:confirm_logout="false"
                facebook:fetch_user_info="true"
                />
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/greeting"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>
            <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView <!-- 1 error here --->
                    android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    facebook:preset_size="normal"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/postStatusUpdateButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Post Status Update"
                    />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/postPhotoButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Post Photo"
                    />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/pickFriendsButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pick Some Friends"
                    />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/pickPlaceButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pick Place"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

There's something wrong with the properties:
[image]

What did I missed?

Comment: justo do a **project -> clean** and see if it worked. if not it is a resources file issue. What errors are there in the layout?

Comment: referenced the facebook sdk library in your android app?

Comment: Cleaning didnt worked, It is written in my post.
@Raghunandan There is something wrong, screen in main post.

Comment: @krzakov have reference the library in your project. I guess you have not. Check by right clicking on your project goto properties android and check if you have the facebook library referenced

Comment: It's your build path, you need to import facebook library again. It should be open on your workspace, then just add it in the button on your right. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used facebook UI elements in your xml file. It seems that your android project isn't able to get the reference of FaceBook SDK as may you have deleted or moved it somewhere. You can verify it by:

Right on project from Project Explore --> Select Properties  -->Select Android --> Check if has correct reference of FaceBook SDK.

Once you provide correct reference... build error will disappear after clean and build.

Comment: that's right, if you have a red cross in your libraries just remove your imported facebook library and import it again!

Comment: I cant add it again, just a gray wizard

Comment: Download Facebook SDK from their Dev site if you don't have now. Add it to Eclipse by "Import Android Code to workspace". Once done... you will be able to add it to your project.

Comment: Ok guys, toss the coin who should have answer

Comment: have a nice week guys :) nice coding!

Answer (score 2):

Answers have been given, so this is only to clarify why the error is occurring :

The R file can only be generated if all resources are compiled. As you have noticed, you have errors in your resources (probably related to the proper inclusion of the FB SDK), which prevent the R.java file from being generated. Since the file does not exist, it cannot be resolved `R cannot be resolved to a variable`.

Eclipse offers to either import a similarly-named class (android.R) or to create something named R (be it a class, an enum, a variable ...), none of these solution are what you need in this case.

From the screenshot you gave, there is something wrong with the import of the FB SDK. Select Remove, and Add it again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Import the Facebook **library**
- **Clean** your project
- **Import** com.your.package.R (where you need to use resources)

Comment: I think I said that in the comments @Philipp

Answer (score 0):

First check your xml files to be sure that they're valid and not generating any errors

Then, try importing R with a fully qualified package name like this:

```
import.com.xyz.R;
```

Then save the file.

Comment: answer has been given